# Download image from url and set in LinearLayout Background in android?

Tags: android, image, background, android-linearlayout

i want to download the image from url and set in background in linear layout not in imageview in android

here i put my code for image download from url but now i want to set image in MY LINER LAYOUT BACKGROUND how to do this

you can see in image in red background that is the layout background i want to set this backgroud dynamically load from url

[image]

**RestaurantActivity.java**

```
public class RestaurantActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener  {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

             int loader = R.drawable.loader;

        Linearlayout middle =(Linearlayout)findviewbyid(R....);

        ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
        String profileimageurl=spreferences.getString("image", "");
        imgLoader.DisplayImage(profileimageurl, loader, imageprofile);

        }
```

**ImageLoader.java**

```
public class ImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService; 

    public ImageLoader(Context context){
        fileCache=new FileCache(context);
        executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    int stub_id = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    public void DisplayImage(String url, int loader, ImageView imageView)
    {
        stub_id = loader;
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
        if(bitmap!=null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(loader);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
    {
        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }
    }

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u;
            imageView=i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
            this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
        }

        public void run() {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
            memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
            Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if(bitmap!=null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.yourLinearLayoutid);
        BitmapDrawable drawableBitmap=new BitmapDrawable(getBitmap(urlString));
        linearLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(drawableBitmap);
```

Method to get Bitmap:

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
    {


        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }
    }
```

Above is the code which  helps to set Background for your Layout...

Comment: BitmapDrawable is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

Personally, instead of passing the `ImageView` to your ImageDownloader. I would create an interface.

```
interface ImageDownloadedCallback {
  void gotImage(Bitmap image);
}
```

Then pass the image back to the callback in your activity.

```
final Linearlayout middle =(Linearlayout)findviewbyid(R....);

ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
String profileimageurl=spreferences.getString("image", "");
imgLoader.DisplayImage(profileimageurl, loader, new ImageDownloadedCallback(){
  void gotImage(Bitmap bm){
    middle.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bm));
  }
});
```

That way you can be much more abstract in what you can set.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void setImagebackground(View view,String url) {
        try {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            URL x2 = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) x2.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            Drawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(myBitmap);
            view.setBackgroundDrawable(dr);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Usage**

```
LinerLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
setimageview(layout,"https://link/to/image.png");
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.